# Python Sound Splicing

Tags: python, audio, jython, splice

I am working on a program that takes in an audio file, locates and then removes any silence from the file. At this point the program runs, but when we play the returned sound, it is simply a slowed down version of the original file. This function takes in a sound file, then the start and stop time of a silent segment. The function then makes two clips (a clip before, and a clip after the silence) and puts those two clips together in the target sound object.

```
    def spliceAudio(audio, start, stop):
      clipOneStart = 0
      clipOneEnd = start - 1
      clipTwoStart = stop + 1
      clipTwoEnd = getLength(audio) - 1 
      target = makeEmptySound(getLength(audio) - (stop-start)) 
      index = 0 
      for source in range(clipOneStart, clipOneEnd): 
         value = getSampleValueAt(audio, source) 
         setSampleValueAt(target, index, value)
         index = index + 1 
      for source in range(clipTwoStart, clipTwoEnd):
         value - getSampleValueAt(audio, source)
         setSampleValueAt(target, index, value)
         index = index + 1 
      play(target)
      return target
```

To me, everything looks like it should be working, but it is not giving us the expected results. Any ideas?

Comment: `value - getSampleValueAt(audio, source)`. Is that hyphen a typo?

Comment: Oops, yup. Fixing that did not change the target sound object, though.

Comment: Idk if this helps but iirc Echo Nest API should be useful; also check out forever.fm. The developer discusses at length on his blog how he works with a number of cutting, splitting and splicing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic looks alright. Common problems with audio playback speed involve the parameters you assign to the audio data, specifically:

- Sampling frequency
- Number of channels
- Bit depth (may not be relevant since it looks like the data is stored in an array)

I don't have any experience with jython, but there's nothing in your code to suggest that any of these parameters are being set for `target` when you call the `makeEmptySound()` function. I imagine they will have default values, but worth checking what these are and whether they match your input data.

Comment: okay so i updated the target variable to this:
     target = makeEmptySound(getLength(audio) - (stop-start), int(getSamplingRate(audio)))
Now it is playing at normal speed but doesn't seem to be cutting anything out.

Comment: @user3386133 - In that case all I can suggest is that you try to diagnose the problem by either (or a combination of): playing `target` after initialisation and between the two loops; printing out `value` and `getSampleValueAt(target, index)` within the loop to check it is being extracted and set properly.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that if `start` and `stop` are very close together then you might not notice it cutting anything out, since common sampling frequency for audio is 44100Hz. Even a very small time step of 0.05s is 2000 or so samples.